# Value of n for which divergence of A is 0

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, spherical-coordinates, divergence-operator

I remember having solved this question a few years back in a very elegant way, it's from GATE 2012.

A is given to be a radial vector (radially outward from origin) with it's magnitude $|A| = kr^n$. So if $\vec r = x \hat i + y \hat j + z \hat k$ then $\vec r . \vec r = ||r|| = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$.

We need to find $n$ such that $\nabla . A = 0$.

[image: a picture of the question]

Ok below is how I remember solving it.

[image: my attempt at a solution]

$$\nabla A = kn r^{n-1} |r| + kr^n 2r = knr^n (n+2)$$

So we get the answer $n = -2$.

By going to the spherical coordinate system, I observed that the vector is completely along $\hat e_r$. So the gradiant can be written as a partial derivative w.r.t r after a dot product with the unit r vector.

But I'm not clear about if I can keep the norm of $r$ seperate from $r^{n-1}$. If I am being correct, I'm getting $n = -1$ as the answer. Also won't $\hat e_r . \hat e_r = 1$, since we write $A= |A|\hat e_r$.

[image: a more correct way]

So my question is how can I solve this in an elegant manner. Is the answer $-2$? Is my proof salvageable?

Comment: For starters, you shouldn't write a hat over a vector unless it's a unit vector. Both in the typed text and in your handwriting, you've left off the square from $\|\vec r\|^2$. Next, in the last line, you've written equality between things that aren't possibly equal. Where have you written the formula for divergence in spherical coordinates? This is very hard to follow.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do a complete rewrite and make edits within 2 days. I actually realised I had gotten confused between the gradient of A and divergence of A. I did the calculations for the gradient... I was actually thinking of deleteing this question now, the solution given in the first picture makes sense once I understood it was the gradient.